# Is it possible to adjust all elements(tags) in HTMLwith Style(auto width or height) at once?

Tags: html, css, tags

I tried to make some changes to HTML Code below and used styles for width and height to make the elements responsive for all pages but I could not figure out how to make all below elements responsive on smaller screens such as Cellphones and Ipads. I fill it should be a way to adjust everything based on the background picture or any first tag or page.

Here is the code so far I wrote:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{lang_login_title}</title>
        <meta name="description" content="{lang_login_desc}" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{SC_LIB_PROJECT}online-shop/main.css">
        <!--SC_JS_LIB-->
        <!--SC_PAGE_CHARSET-->              
    </head>

    <body class="page-background" style="background-image:url('{SC_LIB_PROJECT}online-shop/login/golden.jpg');"> 
        <div class="page">
            <div class="container-small container-alpha">
                <div class="background">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h1>
                            Client Panel
                        </h1>

                        <p>
                            Data Technology, California, USA
                        </p>

                        <p></p>
                        <p>
                            Instagram Page: 
                        </p>
                        <p>
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/cutiesiberianhusky/">@CutieSiberianHusky</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <form class="form"  action="" {SC_FORM_ATTR}>
                    <!--SC_FORM_HIDDEN-->
                    <h2>
                        
                    </h2>

                    <div class="control">
                        <label class="label" for="name">{lang_login}</label>
                        <input class="input {SC_FIELD_CLASS}"  type="text" placeholder="{lang_login}" {SC_FIELD_INFO_login}>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control">
                        <label class="label" for="pass">{lang_password}</label>
                        <!--<input class="input {SC_FIELD_CLASS}" type="password" placeholder="{lang_password}" {SC_FIELD_INFO_password}>-->
                        <input class="input {SC_FIELD_CLASS}" type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control {SC_FIELD_CLASS}" {SC_FIELD_INFO_pswd}>

                    </div>

                    <div class="submit">
                        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Login" {SC_FORM_SUBMIT_INFO} />
                    </div>
                    <!-- Idiomas -->
                    <div class="flag-lang">
                        <a class="flags" href="../login/login.php?lang=en"><img src="{SC_LIB_PROJECT}online-shop/img/en_us.png"></a>
                        <a class="flags" href="../login/login.php?lang=pt"><img src="{SC_LIB_PROJECT}online-shop/img/pt_br.png"></a>
                        <a class="flags" href="../login/login.php?lang=es"><img src="{SC_LIB_PROJECT}online-shop/img/es_es.png"></a>
                    </div>
                    <hr style="margin: 25px 0 20px;">
                    <div id='message'>
                        {SC_FIELD_INFO_Links} 
                        <!--<p style="color:#333;font-size:12px;"><b>{lang_new_user}</b></p>
                        <p style="color:#333;font-size:12px;"><b>{lang_login_to_access}</b></p>
                        <p style="color:#333;font-size:12px;"><b>{lang_login}:</b> admin</p>
                        <p style="color:#333;font-size:12px;"><b>{lang_password}:</b> admin</p>-->
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="copyright">
            <p>©2021 Data Technology. All rights reserved.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is how it look like in large screens:

[image]

And here is how it look like in smaller screen size(for example: Iphone X):

[image]

I would be appreciate if someone help me to see how to use style and width on this or if there is another way to adopt all elements based on screen size once. I know how to do this in SWIFT but I am not sure how to do it in HTML

Answer (score 1):

you try to use (**@media screen**) in your css.

source [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: Is there anyway to do it on HTML instead of CSS since I do not have any experience in CSS

Comment: HTML can't, only CSS can. you have to start from scratch, so that you better understand how CSS works.